# Principal investigator that runs 2 labs at 2 different universities?

Tags: professorship

I found a principal investigator that appears to have 2 labs at 2 different universities at the same time. In [University of Cambridge](http://divf.eng.cam.ac.uk/birl/Main/Research) and [ETH Zurich](http://www.birl.ethz.ch/research/index).

Also, the 2 labs are doing the same research.

How does this work? Surely he can't be flying back and forth between UK and Switzerland everyday?

Comment: A relative of mine runs business in three cities, one of which is in another country. The simple and obvious answer is that he's not doing everything by himself. Even a PI with just one lab doesn't work alone! And I would be wary of claiming it is the same research - related work performed by two groups with a single PI for coherence seems to be a very good idea, where neither group could do enough of both projects, and neither project would progress well if done separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ETH Zurich website clearly states on the right edge that the lab has relocated to Cambridge.

A few faculty do fly between institutions on a regular basis.  I suspect it works poorly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! ETH Zurich should have just removed the lab  from the list though, this is very misleading.

Comment: @Quevun usually universities do not remember to do that.